# Android - IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity, Caused by InvocationTargetException

Tags: android, illegalstateexception, numberformatexception, invocationtargetexception

I'm taking a Coursera Android course and am trying to complete an app that I started. I'm trying to get an animation to occur at set intervals. [See here for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21667916/android-how-can-i-make-an-animation-of-an-image-occur-at-a-certain-interval)

I looked at a lot of posts with the same title, but everyone seems to have different solutions. I don't get an errors in Eclipse when it saves and compiles.

Here's my Logcat results:

```
    02-09 22:56:10.811: E/AndroidRuntime(29538): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-09 22:56:10.811: E/AndroidRuntime(29538): Process: stacy.example.assignment3_stacy_v1, PID: 29538
02-09 22:56:10.811: E/AndroidRuntime(29538): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
02-09 22:56:10.811: E/AndroidRuntime(29538):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
02-09 22:56:10.811: E/AndroidRuntime(29538):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
02-09 22:56:10.811: E/AndroidRuntime(29538):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
02-09 22:56:10.811: E/AndroidRuntime(29538):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-09 22:56:10.811: E/AndroidRuntime(29538):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-09 22:56:10.811: E/AndroidRuntime(29538):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-09 22:56:10.811: E/AndroidRuntime(29538):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-09 22:56:10.811: E/AndroidRuntime(29538):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-09 22:56:10.811: E/AndroidRuntime(29538):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-09 22:56:10.811: E/AndroidRuntime(29538):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-09 22:56:10.811: E/AndroidRuntime(29538):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-09 22:56:10.811: E/AndroidRuntime(29538):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-09 22:56:10.811: E/AndroidRuntime(29538): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-09 22:56:10.811: E/AndroidRuntime(29538):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-09 22:56:10.811: E/AndroidRuntime(29538):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-09 22:56:10.811: E/AndroidRuntime(29538):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
02-09 22:56:10.811: E/AndroidRuntime(29538):    ... 11 more
02-09 22:56:10.811: E/AndroidRuntime(29538): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
02-09 22:56:10.811: E/AndroidRuntime(29538):    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
02-09 22:56:10.811: E/AndroidRuntime(29538):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
02-09 22:56:10.811: E/AndroidRuntime(29538):    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
02-09 22:56:10.811: E/AndroidRuntime(29538):    at stacy.example.assignment3_stacy_v1.Assignment3MainActivity.startRhythmandAnimation(Assignment3MainActivity.java:41)
02-09 22:56:10.811: E/AndroidRuntime(29538):    ... 14 more
```

MainActivity.java

```
package stacy.example.assignment3_stacy_v1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Assignment3MainActivity extends Activity {


    private EditText mMileTimeGoal;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private View mLeftfoot;
    private Animation mFootAnim;
    private long mInterval = 1000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_assignment3_main);
        //mMileTimeGoal = findViewById(R.id.miletimegoal);
        mMileTimeGoal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.miletimegoal);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.assignment3_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void startRhythmandAnimation (View view) {

        //String MileTime = mMileTimeGoal.getContext().toString();
        String MileTime = mMileTimeGoal.getText().toString();
        String[] time_array = MileTime.split(":");
        int hours = Integer.parseInt(time_array[0]);
        int minutes = Integer.parseInt(time_array[1]);
        int seconds = Integer.parseInt(time_array[2]);
        int duration = 3600 * hours + 60 * minutes + seconds;
        int steps_per_second = 3;

        int running_rate = duration * steps_per_second;

        /*
        View rightfoot = findViewById(R.id.rightfoot);
        View leftfoot = findViewById(R.id.leftfoot);

        rightfoot.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.makeInChildBottomAnimation(this);
        rightfoot.startAnimation(anim);

        leftfoot.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        leftfoot.startAnimation(anim);
        */

        mHandler = new Handler(); //.os package class when importing
           mLeftfoot = findViewById(R.id.leftfoot);
           //mFootAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.mleftfoot);
           mFootAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.id.leftfoot);
           stepRecursive();
        }

        private void stepRecursive() {
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mLeftfoot.startAnimation(mFootAnim);
                    stepRecursive();
                }
            }, mInterval);
    }

    public void resetTimetoZeroes () {
        String MileTime = mMileTimeGoal.getContext().toString();
        //Int MileTime = 0;
    }

}
```

Layout xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Assignment3MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/leftfoot"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/rightfoot"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rightfoot"
        android:src="@drawable/leftfoot" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/miletimegoal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="time"
        android:hint="Mile Time Goal?" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rightfoot"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="74dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="36dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rightfoot" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/leftfoot"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/leftfoot"
        android:onClick="startRhythmandAnimation"
        android:text="@string/start_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/resetbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/startbutton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/startbutton"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rightfoot"
        android:text="@string/reset_button"
        android:onClick="resetTimetoZeroes" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT - Here's the latest logcat messages. Please ignore the time calculation code. I would like to get the animation working first!**

```
02-09 23:42:32.291: E/AndroidRuntime(32320): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-09 23:42:32.291: E/AndroidRuntime(32320): Process: stacy.example.assignment3_stacy_v1, PID: 32320
02-09 23:42:32.291: E/AndroidRuntime(32320): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
02-09 23:42:32.291: E/AndroidRuntime(32320):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
02-09 23:42:32.291: E/AndroidRuntime(32320):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
02-09 23:42:32.291: E/AndroidRuntime(32320):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
02-09 23:42:32.291: E/AndroidRuntime(32320):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-09 23:42:32.291: E/AndroidRuntime(32320):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-09 23:42:32.291: E/AndroidRuntime(32320):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-09 23:42:32.291: E/AndroidRuntime(32320):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-09 23:42:32.291: E/AndroidRuntime(32320):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-09 23:42:32.291: E/AndroidRuntime(32320):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-09 23:42:32.291: E/AndroidRuntime(32320):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-09 23:42:32.291: E/AndroidRuntime(32320):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-09 23:42:32.291: E/AndroidRuntime(32320):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-09 23:42:32.291: E/AndroidRuntime(32320): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-09 23:42:32.291: E/AndroidRuntime(32320):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-09 23:42:32.291: E/AndroidRuntime(32320):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-09 23:42:32.291: E/AndroidRuntime(32320):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
02-09 23:42:32.291: E/AndroidRuntime(32320):    ... 11 more
02-09 23:42:32.291: E/AndroidRuntime(32320): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f090000 type #0x12 is not valid
02-09 23:42:32.291: E/AndroidRuntime(32320):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2314)
02-09 23:42:32.291: E/AndroidRuntime(32320):    at android.content.res.Resources.getAnimation(Resources.java:963)
02-09 23:42:32.291: E/AndroidRuntime(32320):    at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AnimationUtils.java:71)
02-09 23:42:32.291: E/AndroidRuntime(32320):    at stacy.example.assignment3_stacy_v1.Assignment3MainActivity.startRhythmandAnimation(Assignment3MainActivity.java:79)
```

**I forgot to post my foot.xml file!**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="-15" android:duration="400"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0" android:duration="400" />
</set>
```

**Fixed my Resource Exception with the following:**

```
mFootAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.foot);
```

Comment: which is your line number 41?

Comment: line 41 is int hours = Integer.parseInt(time_array[0]);

Comment: I edited my answer. Please review. It parse date first. If there is any error, it will stop execution and show you a message.

Comment: ResourceNotFound exception fixed! mFootAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.foot); I needed to reference the foot folder. I forgot to post that. Sorry!

Comment: please mark answer to provide good answer among other for Googler :)

Comment: Please ask multiple questions in multiple threads on Stackoverflow, it is hard to grasp from what I can read up there what your problem really is. Is there even a problem left? It seem you fixed one after the other

Comment: Ok, updated the post. Chintan was a big help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be like below to prevent exception

```
public void startRhythmandAnimation(View view) {

    // String MileTime = mMileTimeGoal.getContext().toString();
    String MileTime = mMileTimeGoal.getText().toString();

    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        Date dt = formatter.parse(MileTime);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(dt);
        int hours = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        int minutes = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int seconds = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);

        int duration = 3600 * hours + 60 * minutes + seconds;
        int steps_per_second = 3;

        int running_rate = duration * steps_per_second;

        mHandler = new Handler(); // .os package class when importing
        mLeftfoot = findViewById(R.id.leftfoot);
        // mFootAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.mleftfoot);
        mFootAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.id.leftfoot);
        stepRecursive();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(Assignment3MainActivity.this,
                "Please Enter Valid Time Stamp", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: I cannot get past this line:  Date dt = formatter.parse(MileTime); Unhandled exception type ParseException.

Comment: @StacyM, i checked my code by passing "18:12:02" in argument. Its working fine. You are not passing value in format. :)

Comment: I still get 02-10 00:13:23.651: E/AndroidRuntime(3688): Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "104040" (at offset 6)
instead of your Toast message! Why isn't the catch preventing the app from crashing with the Unparseable date error?

Comment: Its preventing. I pass your data "104040" and its showing me error without crash..

Comment: Thanks Chintan! I kept looking for ParseException instead of just "Excpetion" on the catch.

Comment: @StacyM, I knew about generic `Exception` class but didn't have time to update yesterday. Great, you found it helpful and got your answer. Glad to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that when you split MileTime, one of the values in the array is an empty string, judging by the following line:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
```

Put a log statement or breakpoint after you do the split and check the values of `time_array`  to be sure

Comment: Ok, that helped. I have a general idea of what to fix for the NumberFormat Exception. I'm still not sure what to do about this one - Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: I'll need a full stack trace to find the root cause

Answer (score -1):

for the 2nd error,Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f090000 type #0x12 is not valid
clean the project and see if R.java gets generated again, if not, look  at your project folder and see if all files are there